# Timeout test does not return TimeoutException - rxjava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

The test fails as there is no exception thrown. It simply completes instead of timing out.

```
    @Test
    fun timeout() {
        val testScheduler = TestScheduler()

        val sub = Observable.just(true)
                .filter{ it -> !it }
                .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)

        val testSubscriber = sub.subscribeOn(testScheduler).test()

        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        testSubscriber.assertError(TimeoutException::class.java)
    }
```

I've been at this block for over an hour and I just don't see why it's failing. It's probably something super obvious, but I feel I need another set of eyes to point it out for me.

Comment: `just` is a finite source and the sequence completes without any items and with no delay. What were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ah of course...

Comment: I think you can change it to  `Observable.fromCallable(() -> { return true; })`, and it will behave as expected. `just` is a blocking call.

Comment: @Tuby that's completely wrong.

Comment: @akarnokd I was actually testing a subscription that feeds off a hot observable source. In my test I mocked out the subscription and fed emissions as `Observable.just`, which resulted in test failure. So then I had simplified the test down to this bit with no further luck. I can see that the problem is in fact in `just`. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @akarnokd Why is that wrong? Callable would be executed during `subscribe()` inside `test()` and it would behave the same as `just()`?

Comment: @Tuby `fromCallable` is still finite, the OP, however, tried to replicate a hot, non-terminating `Observable`. Also `just` is not blocking but synchronous.

Comment: @akarnokd Ok I understand, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a test that gets the expected result:

```
@Test
fun timeout() {
    val testScheduler = TestScheduler()

    val sub = Observable.just(true) // 1
            .delaySubscription(Observable.never<Boolean>()) // 2
            .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler) // 3
    val testSubscriber = sub.subscribeOn(testScheduler).test()

    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    testSubscriber.assertError(TimeoutException::class.java)
```

Here's an explanation of what's going on:

1. We just need a `Observable` to start with, the filter you had before was just making this be an empty one
2. We want to [delay the subscription](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) with something that won't finish, so one alternative is an `Observable` than `never` emits
3. From here on, it's the same you had

Comment: +1 for "so one alternative is an Observable than never emits". In my test, the original observable was still emitting a valid `onNext()` so if you advance the time, the successful emission gets sent before `timeout()` has a chance to send the exception.